# Delete punctuation and English characters from text

Tags: unix

I need to remove all punctuation and English character from the text.

How do I do that in Unix?

I have tried:

```
$ sed '~!@#$%^&*()_+{}[];:'\/.,<>`|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' <BACC.txt>without.txt
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `tr` will suit you:

```
tr -d [:punct:][:alpha:]
```

You can list specific characters you want deleted:

```
tr -d [:punct:]IEAOUieaou
```

If you want to replace deleted characters with a space, then use:

```
tr -s [:punct:]IEAOUieaou ' '
```